# Point in polygon using shapely?

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib, shapely

I am running the following script which I believe should be returning TRUE for the point being in the polygon but it is returning FALSE.

```
from shapely import geometry

polygon = [(-1571236.8349707182, 8989180.222117377), (1599362.9654156454, 8924317.946336618), (-1653179.0745812152, 8922145.163675062), (-1626237.6614402141, 8986445.107619021)]

Point_X = -1627875.474
Point_Y = 8955472.968

line = geometry.LineString(polygon)
point = geometry.Point(Point_X, Point_Y)

print(line.contains(point))
```

When I plot the polygon and point in Matlab I get the following shape

[image]

```
from matplotlib import pylab as plt
poly = [[-1571236.8349707182, 8989180.222117377],
    [1599362.9654156454, 8924317.946336618],
    [-1653179.0745812152, 8922145.163675062],
    [-1626237.6614402141, 8986445.107619021]]

x = [point[0] for point in poly]
y = [point[1] for point in poly]

p1 = [-1627875.474, 8955472.968]
p2 = [-1627875.474, 8955472.968]
plt.plot(x,y,p1[0],p1[1],'*r',p2[0],p2[1],'*b')
plt.show()
```

Any idea why the shapely script is returning FALSE?

Comment: It might be because your shape isnt closed. It doesn't know if it's convex or concave, so it can't really make a shape out of what you've given it. You might need to make sure it begins and ends at the same point.

Comment: I tried that -- unfortunately, I get the same answer (FALSE) when I add the beginning point as a fifth coordinate as well.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What you are testing is whether your point is on the object `LineString`.

If you want to test that the point is in the polygon you must use the `contains` methods of class `Polygon`

```
from shapely import geometry

polygon = [(-1571236.8349707182, 8989180.222117377), (1599362.9654156454, 8924317.946336618), (-1653179.0745812152, 8922145.163675062), (-1626237.6614402141, 8986445.107619021)]

Point_X = -1627875.474
Point_Y = 8955472.968

line = geometry.LineString(polygon)
point = geometry.Point(Point_X, Point_Y)
polygon = geometry.Polygon(line)

print(polygon.contains(point))
```

ouput

```
True
```

see https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html

Comment: That works! Thanks so much -- I misunderstood the LineString object.

Answer (score 0):

This code uses geopandas to find point(s) within polygon(s).

```
import geopandas as gpd
points_gpd = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(x, y)) #point coordinates to geopandas dataframe
polygons_gpd = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=polygons) #polygons is a list of shapely polygons
pt2poly = gpd.sjoin(points_gpd,polygons_gpd, predicate='within').index_right #for each point index in the points, it stores the polygon index containing that point
```