# Cleaning Latitude and Longitude Data

Tags: python, data-cleaning

I have been trying to clean data containing Latitude and Longitude values for Boston City. The problem I am facing is, data contain a lot of noise. I removed NULL, NAN, NA & 0 values from it. But the data still contains locations from South Africa which is inconsistent and noise for me as it does not contribute to my analysis.

### My Problem:

> **I want to eliminate every location that doesn't fall inside the boundaries of Boston City.**

- I am pasting all info of the data although I am working with just two columns ('Lat' and 'Long')

```
    <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 299074 entries, 0 to 319072
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count   Dtype  
---  ------  --------------   -----  
 0   Long    299074 non-null  float64
 1   Lat     299074 non-null  float64
dtypes: float64(2)
memory usage: 6.8 MB
```

If you need any info feel free to ask.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Point in polygon using shapely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52281055/point-in-polygon-using-shapely)

Comment: @Joe Thanks for suggesting the answer although it relates to what I have asked but the problem I face is state or country cannot be an easy polygon with 5/6/7 vertices. It will be really hard for me to  shape Boston as a polygon and then try finding all the vertices manually.

Comment: I am not sure what you are up to, but usually you download the polygon for Boston or whatever somewhere, some GIS service, Openstreetmap, etc.

Comment: Think of it a large number of Lat and Long pairs distributed over map. Just those pairs you have nothing else. Now you want to filter them based on the country they lie in.

Comment: Yes, that's a very very basic task. You use some in-polygon algorithm and use it like that `inpolygon(my_county, my_points)`. And as a result you get something like `True, False, True`, one boolean value for each element in `my_points`. Then you could use Numpy boolean indexing or whatever to filter the complete list. Or just append them to a new list.

Comment: Thanks @Joe I am sorry I didn't connected your previous suggestion very well but I did researched today and found that this algo can be really handy for my task