# Points in which polygon

Tags: python, coordinates, polygon, point, shapely

I have several (order of M) points [(x0,y0),...,(xn,yn)]. I also have limited number of hexagons. I want to find each point falls in which hexagon. Using shapely this can be done for 1 point at a time so the loop below does the job. But is there any other way to do it faster?

```
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.geometry.polygon import Polygon
zones = np.zeros(n)-1
for j,p in enumerate(points):
    point = Point(p)
    for i in range(len(poly_hex)): #poly_hex = list of hexagonal polygones
        polygon = Polygon(poly_hex[i])
        if polygon.contains(point):
            zones[j] = int(i)
            break
```

Comment: Is this something that will be done more than once (and often)?

Comment: You can run multiple processes in parallel using the ```multiprocessing``` library, as checking if a point is inside a polygon is an independent task.

Comment: Are they regular hexagons? Are they all of the same size? Are they in a hexagonal grid? Are they allowed to intersect?

Comment: Yes. This is a hexagonal grid. No there is no intersection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looking for a fast way to find the polygon a point belongs to using Shapely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20297977/looking-for-a-fast-way-to-find-the-polygon-a-point-belongs-to-using-shapely)

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas to speed things up:

- Don't convert your hexagons to `polygon = Polygon(poly_hex[i])` at each step of the inner loop. Calculate them once before the loop and store them in a list.
- As the surface of a hexagon is close to a circle, also make a list of just the centre and the radius of the hexagons. Inside the loop, first test the distance between the point `p` and the centre of each hexagon, comparing to the radius. Only in case `p` is less than the radius to the centre, do an explicit test to see whether it is inside the hexagon.
- If this still isn't fast enough, and depending on how small, and how far apart the hexagons are relative to your points, you could speed things up further with a quadtree or a grid. But this is less trivial. If most of the points are outside all hexagons, you could first test whether `p` is inside the convex hull of the hexagons.

Some remarks:

- I don't understand your `zone[j] = int(i)`. You convert `i` to an integer, while it already is an integer. Also, the way you store this, means a point can only be inside maximum one hexagon. Therefore, you can stop the loop as soon as you encountered such a hexagon. (There is also the rare case where a point is just on the edge between two hexagon. This might assign it to the first hexagon encountered. Or, due to rounding errors, even might have it outside both hexagons.)
- If you want to save the zones as integers, create it as: `zones = np.zeros(n, dtype=int)-1`.
- If your hexagons form a regular hexagonal grid, you can find the exact hexagon simply from the x and y coordinates without the need for in-polygon testing.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. For the remarks, without int(i) it was saving the zone numbers as float (1.0, 2.0, ...), which was not what I wanted. That's correct, the hexagons don't layover so each point is at max in one hexagon. I am actually breaking the inner loop when the first hexagon is found.

Comment: The zones are still saved as floats, because you have a general numpy array (which gets type np.float64).  Try `zones = np.zeros(n, dtype=int)-1` to get integers.